# Writing categories as slice categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a known method to write any category $ C $ as being equivalent to a slice category bundle $ \bar{C}_{/c}\to\bar{C} $, where $ C\simeq \bar{C}_{/c} $? It seems one can try to find a category $\bar{C}$ and some $ c\in\bar{C}$ with $\int \bar{C}[-,c] \to \bar{C} $ giving the appropriate bundle, where $\int$ denotes the category of elements. Is this a reasonable approach? Where can I read more about this problem? And, is there some kind of free construction that produces a bundle with the property I am looking for?

The motivation for my question is to find out when the correspondence taking objects in $C$ to slice bundles over $C$ can be reversed, so that I can transport problems about functors between slice bundles down to problems about objects in the base category.

**Edit for clarity.** I am looking for what characterizes slice categories without the context of their domain projection. What intrinsic properties distinguish slice categories? As Todd pointed out, they always have terminal objects. Their colimits are reflected by their projection functors, so I imagine we don't have to worry about many colimits existing since the unsliced category may not have many colimits to begin with.

Comment: No, certainly not, since slice categories have a terminal object. But if $C$ does have a terminal object $1$, then trivially $C \simeq C/1$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but can't we freely give a category a terminal object if it does not have one?

Comment: Of course, but then you're changing the category $C$ (to something inequivalent to $C$). Not sure what you're driving at...

Comment: Yes, I suppose I need to weaken what I am looking for. In the case that $C$ has a terminal object, what other obstructions do we have? I think what I am trying to do is classify what categories are equivalent to slice categories.

Comment: But my first comment told you: a category is equivalent to a slice category if and only if it has a terminal object.

Comment: Here is what I thought the question would be: "Given a family of categories indexed by the objects of some other category, under what circumstances can these be made the slice categories for some functor?"

Comment: @ToddTrimble What about more interesting examples? Is there something that I can look for in a category which suggests that we can write it as a slice category over a nonterminal object in the base category?

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon That's an interesting question to me as well, and probably captures the nontrivial cases I had in mind. Can we look for functors between the indexed categories and check somehow that they are induced by a morphism of underlying objects? I suppose there is some clever condition that classifies this property.

Comment: Mathemologist: what base category? I suppose, given categories $D$ and $C$, one can ask about circumstances under which $D$ is equivalent to a slice of $C$, and these might most usefully take the form of suitable comonadic functors $G: D \to C$ (i.e., equivalent to a forgetful functor of the form $\Sigma_X: C/X \to C$, which is comonadic). For this one should consult (co)monadicity theorems, together with conditions which ensure that the relevant comonad is of the form $X \times -: C \to C$ (possibly something to do with creation/reflection of connected limits).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your time! (It's evident, but I want to note that I would upvote your comments if I had the reputation to do so.)

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for what characterizes slice categories without the context of their domain projection. What intrinsic properties distinguish slice categories?

The slice category $C/c$ is the category of element of the representable presheaf $h_c \colon C \to \bf Set$. There is a universal construction characterizing this category, which is being a weighted colimit (these thingssatisfy universal props similar to "conical" co/limits). The nLab page about the category of elements contains all the relevant infos!

Comment: Thank you! I was suspecting this was the case, but I wasn't entirely sure about the validity of my proof.